# What is this stacking game with rotating coloured sides?

Tags: identify-this-game

If anyone could help I would love to find the name of this game.

[image: Black stacking game with rotating sides]

As you stack the block the blocked the sides on the block below rotate and they change color (see the stickers) and there are four "bases" or the bottoms in total.  Have been searching the internet for hours now to no avail, hoping someone has seen this before!

Comment: Is this a multiplayer thing, or more like a one-man puzzle game?

Answer (score 4):

This is from [Chameleon](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/17576/chameleon)

> Its the 3-D building game with a colorful twist! As players race to
>   build towers using their Chameleon' blocks, there's a surprise with
>   every move - the Chameleon blocks magically change their colors!
>
> Place one red block on a tower and the block below turns green. Choose
>   another red block, add it to the tower, and the block below changes to
>   red. You'll need skill and luck to correctly "predict" what colors
>   will appear. Matching colors earns you another turn. If block colors
>   don't match, dismantle the tower, block by block, and start from the
>   ground up!